# Using RegExp to test words for letter count

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been trying to use RegExp in JS to test a string for a certain count of a substrings. I would like a purely RegExp approach so I can combine it with my other search criteria, but have not had any luck.

As a simple example I would like to test a word if it has exactly 2-3 `a`s.

| case | test string | expected result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `cat` | false |
| 2 | `shazam` | true |
| 3 | `abracadabra` | false |

Most of my guesses at regex fail case 3. Example: `^(?<!.*a.*)((.*a.*){2,3})(?!.*a.*)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use this regex.

With any other character, including whitespace.

`^[^a]*(?:a[^a]*){2,3}$`

or if using multi-lines and don't want to span.

`^[^a\r\n]*(?:a[^a\r\n]*){2,3}$`

```
^                  # Begin 
[^a]*              # optional not-a
(?:                # Grp
  a                  # single a
  [^a]*              # optional not-a
){2,3}             # Get 2 or 3 a only
$                  # End
```

https://regex101.com/r/O3SYKx/1

Comment: That makes sense and it works perfect for what I need.  Thank you!